# como cambiar al orden inverso de una matriz

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente código que lo que hace es devolver una matriz en el orden inverso, pero la devuelve en el mismo orden. en resumen si la matriz es [1][2][3], el resultado debería ser [3][2][1] pero me devuelve el mismo orden, creo que el error esta en la forma en la que invierto el orden.

```
    int N[][] = new int[4][4];
    int A, S, Z, D, B;
    
    D=4;
    B=0;
    S=D-1;
    Z=D-1;
    
    for (int c = 0; c < D; c++) {
        for (int f = 0; f < D; f++) {
            B += 1;
            if (B > 9){B = 1;}
            N[c][f] = B;
        }
    }

    for (int c = 0; c < D; c++) {
        for (int f = 0; f < D; f++) {
            A = N[c][f];
            N[c][f] = N[Z][S];
            N[Z][S] = A;
            S= S- 1;
        }
        Z = Z-1;
        S = D-1;
    }
    for (int c = 0; c < D; c++) {
        for (int f = 0; f < D; f++) {
           System.out.print(N[c][f] + " ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
```

Comment: El ejemplo q pones es con un vector no con una matriz, pq no ejemplificas lo que quieres con un ejemplo q realmente describa tu problematica

Comment: Sinceramente, no te van a cobrar nada por poner nombres a las variables. Me pierdo solo de mirar esto: `A = N[c][f]; N[c][f] = N[Z][S]; N[Z][S] = A; S= S- 1;` Dios mio, que *puedas* poner nombres de un único caracter no quiere decir que *debas*!

Comment: perdón xd, era mi primera pregunta aquí, pero gracias por los consejos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final después de tanto pensar xd, llegue a la conclusión de que con la siguiente formula podía encontrar el numero de veces que se tienen que hacer las inversiones de valores para que no quede exactamente igual, la formula es: para números impares **(n^2/2)** y para números impares **(n^2/2) + (n/2)** , siendo n el tamaño de la matriz. (cuando digo tamaño de la matriz o **n** me refiero a si es de tamaño 4 la matriz seria 4x4)

Cabe recalcar que primero hice una formula que tenia un error para matrices de tamaño 7 o superior, en el cual se repetía la fila del medio, la formula que usaba antes era **2^(n-1)**.

Estas formulas solo sirven para matrices cuadradas.

Además de esto, estas formulas fueron ideadas y creadas por mi parte y me gustaría fuesen utilizadas para estos casos. (me alargue mucho xd)

```
    int temporal, fila_in, columna_in, tamaño_m, b, cont_r;

    tamaño_m = 5;
    b = 0; //para rellenar la matriz
    cont_r = 0; //contador de veces que se intercambia un valor en la matriz
    fila_in = tamaño_m - 1; //contador inverso para intercambiar valores en las filas
    columna_in = tamaño_m - 1; //contador inverso para intercambiar valores en las columnas

    int Matriz[][] = new int[tamaño_m][tamaño_m];

    System.out.print("Matriz ingresada \n");
    
    //esta parte solo es para rellenar la matriz
    
    for (int columna = 0; columna < tamaño_m; columna++) {
        for (int fila = 0; fila < tamaño_m; fila++) {
            b += 1;
            Matriz[columna][fila] = b;
            System.out.print("[" + Matriz[columna][fila] + "]" + " ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }

    System.out.print("Matriz en orden inverso \n");
    
    //esta es la de intercambio de valores en la matriz

    for (int columna = 0; columna < tamaño_m; columna++) {
        for (int fila = 0; fila < tamaño_m; fila++) {
            if ((tamaño_m % 2) == 0) {  //este if es para aplicar la formula dependiendo si el tamaño de la matriz es par o impar
                if (cont_r <= ((tamaño_m / 2) * tamaño_m)) {    //con este if aplicamos el resultado de la formula para saber hasta cuando se va a repetir tomando en cuenta la variable cont_r
                    temporal = Matriz[columna][fila];                       //aqui guardamos el valor de la celda en una variable temporal
                    Matriz[columna][fila] = Matriz[columna_in][fila_in];    //aqui igualamos la celda a su inversa  
                    Matriz[columna_in][fila_in] = temporal;                 //igualamos la inversa al valor que guardamos en la variable temporal
                    cont_r += 1;                                            //le restamos 1 a la variable cont_r     
                    if (tamaño_m == 2 && cont_r == 2) {         //este if es para solucionar un error de la formula cuando el tamaño es de 2 (2x2)
                        cont_r += 1;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (cont_r <= ((tamaño_m / 2) * tamaño_m) + (tamaño_m / 2) + 0.5) { //en este if se hace lo mismo pero la formula cambia para números impares.
                    temporal = Matriz[columna][fila];
                    Matriz[columna][fila] = Matriz[columna_in][fila_in];
                    Matriz[columna_in][fila_in] = temporal;
                    cont_r += 1;
                }
            }
            fila_in = fila_in - 1; //le restamos 1 al contador inverso para que avance a la celda que sigue en el orden
        }
        columna_in = columna_in - 1;      //le restamos 1 al contador inverso de las columnas para que avance a la siguiente columna
        fila_in = tamaño_m - 1;   //volvemos a igualar el contador de la fila para que 
    }

    //este for es para imprimir el vector después de que se le hayan hecho los cambios
    
    for (int c = 0; c < tamaño_m; c++) {
        for (int f = 0; f < tamaño_m; f++) {
            System.out.print("[" + Matriz[c][f] + "]" + " ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
```

Este código es para cambiar la matriz y no para cambiar el orden de impresión de la misma en consola

Answer (score 1):

He hecho un código que te puede solucionar tu problema explicando con comentarios que es lo que voy haciendo en cada momento, espero que te ayude!

```
        int resultado = 0;
        int aniadir = 1;

        int matriz[][] = new int[4][4];    //Definimos el arreglo

        System.out.println("Array normal\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {   //Se repetira mientras que 'i' sea menor a '4' para poder recorrer el array completo
            System.out.print("\n"); //Salto de linea para mostrar la siguiente fila
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {   //Se repetira mientras que 'i' sea menor a '4' para poder recorrer el array completo
                resultado = aniadir++;  // Vamos aniadiendo aniadir++ a resultado en cada iteracion, consiguiendo que se incremente en uno en cada bucle.
                matriz[i][j] = resultado;   //Le damos los valores de resultado a la matriz.
                System.out.print(matriz[i][j] + "\t");// Mostramos la posicion del array indicada por el bucle, siendo 'i' la fila y 'j' la columna
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\n\nArray dado la vuelta\n");

        for (int i = 3; i > -1; i--) {  //Recorremos el array pero empezando por atras para mostrarlo al reves
            System.out.print("\n");
            for (int j = 3; j > -1; j--) {  //Si te das cuenta la matriz haria lo siguiente: matriz[3][3], matriz[3][2], matriz[3][1], matriz[2][3]...
                //Mostrara la matriz al reves.
                System.out.print(matriz[i][j] + "\t");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias bro

Answer (score 0):

Puedes recorrer la matriz de forma inversa y almacenar los valores de cada elemento en otra matriz idéntica (clon). Para ello el **for** de las iteraciones deber ser algo así:

```
for (j = 4; j >= 0; j--)
```

Donde j es la longitud de la matriz.

El ejemplo que te proporciono es para c#.